# How to save gif picture into Camera Roll or Saved Pictures in WP8？

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to save gif picture into Camera Roll or Saved Pictures, but I have not find 
a valid way to do it. The Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary can save jpeg 
files, I tried to save a gif file with this method, but it only save the first frame 
with jpeg fomat.

I find that Nokia Cinemagraph can save GIF files, and I can play the saved gif file 
while I copy it to another folder without the npo file.
Can I do it like Cinemagraph with WP8 SDK? It would also be fine with Windows Phone 
Runtime or pure C++ if it's not possible with C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is anyone knowns about this proprolem? I've heard GIF suport should be coming with Apollo+.

Answer (score 2):

In my knowledge there is no way to save the .gif file into the Camera roll. However you can change the .gif file to .jpg format first rather than save .gif file.

As a first step, you have to convert the .gif file into WriteableBitmap. Because it can save any UIElement.

```
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(".gif file",null);
```

Finally we can use the following steps to create the jpg stream of bits from the `WriteableBitmap`

```
using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
{
     bitmap.SaveJpeg(s, (int)ContentPanel.Width, (int)ContentPanel.Height, 0, 100);
}
```

this bits of stream can be saved into the Camera Roll using the following method.

```
lib.SavePictureToCameraRoll("A",s);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.But an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll when "SavePictureToCameraRoll" runs.I think this method would encode the MemoryStream s into jpeg format rather than gif fomat.

Comment: Check capabilities in your manifest. You should have CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO